# Controls in a WPF UserControl don`t raise lost focus

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I have a MainWindow with 3 main buttons at the top and below a MainUserControl.

**In the MainUserControl** I have at top 3 UserControls with ButtonBars 
and at the bottom a DataGrid.

When I enter data in a DataGridCell and **I click into another cell** a property change is fired in my ViewModel bound to the DataGrid.

When I enter data... and **I click on one of the 3 main buttons** again a property change is fired because of Lost Focus event.

When I ... and I **click on one of the buttons in the ButtonBar in the UserControl** *no property change is fired* because there seem to be no Lost Focus event.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False" on the UserControl or other elements like Menu solved the problem and my property changes are raised now in the model :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change your binding to to set **UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged** then you will not need to rely on the LostFocus to do a property update.

Comment: can not do that because when I leave a DataGridCell I do a database update of the changed text in the DataGridCell. If I would change UpdateSourceTrigger from LostFocus to your suggested PropertyChanged I would get many sql inserts for every char you type...